# Elasticsearch autocomplete with misspelling

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create autocomplete with similar functionality as [Apollo graphql](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/) has. Basically it:

1. searches as I type
2. handles typos
3. gives the most weigh to headers then subheaders and at last to content

While in Apollo graphql doc this functionality is provided by algolia I was pretty sure that I can built it with elasticsearch.

I started with [Search-as-you-type field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-as-you-type.html#search-as-you-type) and easily made it work as follow.

Mapping:

```
PUT /article
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "search_as_you_type"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some dummy data:

```
PUT /article/_bulk
{ "index": {"_id": "1"} }
{   "title": "Authentication and authorization", "subtitle": "Putting authenticated user info on the context" }
```

And searching:

```
GET /article/_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "auth",
            "type": "bool_prefix",
            "fuzziness" : "AUTO",
            "prefix_length" : 2,
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "title._2gram",
                "title._3gram",
                "title._index_prefix"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get following:

```
a -> Authentication and authorization
au -> Authentication and authorization
aut -> Authentication and authorization
...
```

But when I misspell a word to `autentication` ES return nothing.

After some research I found out that `fuzziness` does'n work with `bool_prefix`. See:

- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/56229
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/fuzziness-not-work-with-bool-prefix-multi-match-search-as-you-type/229602/3

So please is there some other way how to achieve this desired behavior? Or elasticsearch technology is just incapable to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @Hi, did you find a solution for your problem? Facing the same issue